# Generate ranges given arrays of starts and stops

Tags: python, numpy

Given 2 arrays of starts and stops, is there a way to generate arrays of sequential numbers in numpy without resorting to loops? For example:

```
start = np.array([1, 3, 5])
stop  = np.array([4, 5, 7])

# Expected result
[
 [1, 2, 3, 4],
 [3, 4, 5],
 [5, 6, 7]
]
```

`linspace` comes closest to what I want but I must use the same number of steps for every series:

```
np.linspace(start, stop, num=3, axis=1)
array([[1. , 2.5, 4. ],
       [3. , 4. , 5. ],
       [5. , 6. , 7. ]])
```

How can I vary the number of steps for each individual series?

Comment: Since the results can vary in length, you have to do some sort of list iteration.  The `linspace` approach works because the sublists are consistent in size.  It can generate one list, and scale the others.  With variable lengths there isn't an array shortcut.

Answer (score 2):

Does a list comprehension count as being "without loops"?

```py
[list(range(a,b+1)) for (a,b) in zip(start, stop)]
```

Comment: `range(a, b)` must be `range(a, b + 1)` instead.

Comment: The "expected result" in the question looks like a list of lists I think

Comment: Thanks for the answer Simon. The result can be a list or an ndarray. I am looking for some vectorized operations since I have it in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious list comprehension:

```
In [92]: [np.arange(i,j) for i,j in zip([1,3,5],[5,6,8])]                                                 
Out[92]: [array([1, 2, 3, 4]), array([3, 4, 5]), array([5, 6, 7])]
In [93]: timeit [np.arange(i,j) for i,j in zip([1,3,5],[5,6,8])]                                          
4.46 µs ± 97.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Note I start with lists, since they iterate faster.

`frompyfunc` is a nice tool for making object dtype arrays:

```
In [94]: f = np.frompyfunc(np.arange, 2,1)                                                                
In [95]: f(np.array([1,3,5]), np.array([5,6,8]))                                                          
Out[95]: 
array([array([1, 2, 3, 4]), array([3, 4, 5]), array([5, 6, 7])],
      dtype=object)
In [96]: timeit f(np.array([1,3,5]), np.array([5,6,8]))                                                   
10.9 µs ± 36.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

but it is slower than the comprehension.

but if we generate lists instead the comprehension is even faster:

```
In [97]: timeit [list(range(i,j)) for i,j in zip([1,3,5],[5,6,8])]                                        
2.38 µs ± 44.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

But look at that magical, vectorized `linspace`:

```
In [98]: np.linspace([1,3,5], [4,5,7], num=3, axis=1)                                                     
Out[98]: 
array([[1. , 2.5, 4. ],
       [3. , 4. , 5. ],
       [5. , 6. , 7. ]])
In [99]: timeit np.linspace([1,3,5], [4,5,7], num=3, axis=1)                                              
87.2 µs ± 260 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

slow!!

But this is small example.  Rankings may change with much larger cases.  In any case, don't assume that 'vectorized' is always faster.  There are plenty of cases where the Python list operations are faster, especially when sizes are modest.  Making numpy arrays is a bit costly - even though once made they are fast.

Answer (score 0):

As @hpaulj stated in comments, you can't have a ragged array, so at least the outer container will have to be a list. You can do this without loops using [`itertools.starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap) and [`numpy.stack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html) or [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
result = list(starmap(np.arange, np.stack(start, stop + 1, axis=-1))
```

OR

```
result = list(starmap(np.arange, zip(start, stop + 1))
```

This isn't exactly vectorized, but doesn't expose any looping keywords. A list comprehension is likely to be faster than either approach.